# Making "%d" string as a macro in c++

Tags: c++, macros

I have a function

```
Format (sOperCnt, SStext ("%d"), m_nOperCnt);
```

Basically, it will set the value `m_perCnt` to `sOperCnt`.  My class contains lot of similar code, so can I use this `"%d"` as a macro and use it everywhere. 
ie

```
#define INT_FORMAT        "%d"
(sOperCnt, INT_FORMAT, m_nOperCnt)
```

I don't know if it is good practice or not.

Comment: IMO, **Yes** `INT_FORMAT` is definitely better than `"%d"` as it provides flexibility to change & track. For example, you can make `"%u"` in 1 shot with that macro. Moreover, you are helping the optimizer to let all the `"%d"`s point to a single read-only location. No accidental extra spaces like `" %d"` will be possible with macro. `INT_FORMAT` is better searchable due to its specific nature.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :-) i dont understand what you mean by "you can make "%u" in 1 shot with that macro" this comment ?

Comment: Another function might be good; `void FormatInt(int x, int y) { Format(x, SStext("%d"), y); }`.

Comment: Format will work for all king on numbers like "%d","%f","%u"

Comment: If you want to avoid using macro's since they can pollute your global namespace...  Use variables.  Define In .h file. and declare in a .cpp(wrapped in a namespace if you want, wrapped in a class if you dislike 'globals').

Comment: @iammilind: The second part is nonsense. `#define` is invisible to the optimizer (since it's replaced in pre-processing).

Comment: @MSalters, no it's not non-sense. If you read the next statement, then you will be able to figure it out. While typing "%d", one may mistakenly type " %d" or "%d " as well, which creates a different string literal from intended "%d". With macro, it's guaranteed that, everywhere only 1 kind of string literal will be replaced. Now, certain compilers (like g++) will optimize & place the same read only string literal at the single address instead of creating multiple copies. Hope that makes the point clear.

Comment: Arjun, suppose you were printing a signed integer using `INT_FORMAT = "%d"` everywhere. Now after a while the variable is changed from "signed" to "unsigned integer". In such case, you can simply change to `#define INT_FORMAT "%u"` instead of searching "%d" everywhere and re-typing. This is just a small side-advantage you get, when you have a macro or a `const char*` as a place holder. Not necessarily useful in all cases. But in general,  manually typed "%d" are difficult to track and replace. Hence better to store them in a variable (1st choice) or macro. In your case both seems fine.

Comment: @iammilind :  That is is really helpful. Thanks :-)

Answer (score -1):

No, generally macro's aren't good practice, and this is no exception. You have a simple constant: `const char* const INT_FORMAT = "%d";`

Comment: A simpler constant is `char const INT_FORMAT[] = "%d";`.

Comment: Macros are NOT always bad. There are many things which can't be achieved without macros. For example, with `const char*`, one cannot leverage the compilers ability of string concatenations, such as `"The cost is " INT_FORMAT`. The answer provides a general advice, but doesn't touch upon the specific question. Why do you feel that using macro in this (question) case is Also bad?